# Curriculum vitae sub-header

Tags: header-footer, templates, moderncv, cv

I'm new to LaTeX, and am wondering if it would be possible to modify the academic CV found here (http://www.tedpavlic.com/post_resume_cv_latex_example.php) to have contact info as a subheader, under the name. My issue with the current format is that I want to place significantly less emphasis on the contact info, and not treat it as an section equivalent to the other content (Qualifications and Interests, Professional Experience, etc.).

Right now the heading command for this CV format is:

```
\newcommand{\makeheading}[2][]%
        {\hspace*{-\marginparsep minus \marginparwidth}%
         \begin{minipage}[t]{\textwidth+\marginparwidth+\marginparsep}%
             {\large \bfseries #2 \hfill #1}\\[-0.15\baselineskip]%
                 \rule{\columnwidth}{1pt}%
         \end{minipage}}
```

Which can be used in this way:

```
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{plain}
\makeheading[\emph{Curriculum vitae}]{John Doe}
```

In PDF form, it basically has "John Doe" in big bold letters on the top left, and "Curriculum vitae" in big bold letters on the top right. Below those words is a long, horizontal line. Would it be possible to have some subheader with contact info, which would go underneath the "John Doe", in non-bold and smaller text, and above the horizontal line?

Alternate proposal:

I've looked at the modern CV template and like the way that they treat contact info as a faint footer. I'm not a fan of how spacious the modern CV template is as a whole, otherwise I would adopt it entirely. If it'd be possible to borrow the contact info section of the modern CV and apply it here, I'd be delighted to use that as a solution, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the definition of command `\makeheading` to use three parameters like

```
\newcommand{\makeheading}[3][]%
        {\hspace*{-\marginparsep minus \marginparwidth}%
         \begin{minipage}[t]{\textwidth+\marginparwidth+\marginparsep}%
             {\large \bfseries #2 \hfill #1}\\ % <============================
             {#3}\\[-0.15\baselineskip]% <====================================
                 \rule{\columnwidth}{1pt}%
         \end{minipage}}
```

and then use it like

```
\makeheading{Dr.~Theodore~(Ted) P.~Pavlic}%
  {Arizona State University~-- % <============================================
  School of Computing, Informatics, and Decision Systems Engineering~-- 
  PO Box 878809, Room 553~-- 
  Tempe, AZ  85287-8809  USA~--  
  \textit{Work:} +1-480-965-2899~-- 
  \textit{Fax:} +1-480-965-2751~-- 
  \textit{E-mail:} \email{tpavlic@asu.edu}~-- 
  \textit{WWW:} \href{http://www.tedpavlic.com/}{www.tedpavlic.com}} % <======
```

With the linked CV you get then the following first pdf page:

[image: first pdf page]

Comment: This is perfect. Thank you so much!